# Set priority for View Events

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-gesture

I have a problem with `OnGestureListener` and `OnTouchListener`. When I run a service with `WindowManager` has `onTouchListener` on a `Actvitiy` that has `onGestureListener`. I cannot get MotionEvents before the Gestures.

How can I set priority for `onTouchListener` to get MotionEvents before?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because `OnGestureListener` has the chance to consume touch events before `OnTouchListener`. If you're the one setting the OnGestureListener, then just override the methods that you want to be passed to your `OnTouchListener` and have them return false.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}
```